# HTTP application to GET, PUT, DELETE

Tags: html, xhtml, bigtable

Do you guys know if there is an application that enables me to use GET, PUT, DELETE HTTP methods in a simple way?

I want to run it against Google's BigTable.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

[curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)?  It has a command-line client as well as libraries (written in C, but with bindings for all the major languages).

You can specify custom methods with -X:

```
curl -X DELETE mysite.appspot.com/foo
```

In the library, you use the [`CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTCUSTOMREQUEST) option.

Comment: Not only, but you can use curl in a variety of languages or even use some of their sample c code to build light tools. Use what is readily available.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows, try [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It not only does logging of browser to server traffic but can also create requests in its own right.